# Problema com conversão android

Tags: android, data, formatação

Tenho uma data que está sendo retornada de um WebService assim:

```
Sep 22, 2014 12:00:00 AM
```

Gostaria de converte-la para o seguinte formato?

```
22/09/2014
```

Tentei alguns métodos utilizando o `Date` do Android e não obtive sucesso.

OBS: A data vem do WebService em formato `String`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a classe [SimpleDateFormat](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

```
public String trocaFormatoData(String data) {

    String formatoDeEntrada = "MMM dd, yyyy h:mm:ss AM";
    String formatoDeSaida = "dd/MM/yyyy";
    SimpleDateFormat dateFormatEntrada = new SimpleDateFormat(formatoDeEntrada);
    SimpleDateFormat dateFormatSaida = new SimpleDateFormat(formatoDeSaida);

    Date dataOriginal = null;
    String dataTrocada = null;

    try {
        //Transforma a String em Date
        dataOriginal = dateFormatEntrada.parse(data);
        //Transforma a Date num String com o formato pretendido
        dataTrocada = dateFormatSaida.format(dataOriginal);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
       //Erro se não foi possível fazer o parse da Data
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return dataTrocada;
}
```

Adaptado de uma [resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17291726/2556111) do SOen

Esta função pode ser tornada mais genérica de forma a trocar um qualquer formato em outro qualquer.
Para isso o formato de entrada e de saída serão parâmetros da função.

```
public String trocaFormatoData(String data, String formatoDeEntrada, String formatoDeSaida) {

    SimpleDateFormat dateFormatEntrada = new SimpleDateFormat(formatoDeEntrada);
    SimpleDateFormat dateFormatSaida = new SimpleDateFormat(formatoDeSaida);

    Date dataOriginal = null;
    String dataTrocada = null;

    try {
        //Transforma a String em Date
        dataOriginal = dateFormatEntrada.parse(data);
        //Transforma a Date num String com o formato pretendido
        dataTrocada = dateFormatSaida.format(dataOriginal);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
       //Erro se não foi possível fazer o parse da Data
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return dataTrocada;
}
```

Comment: Muito Obrigado!

Comment: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/38587/trocar-data-dando-erro