# Erro ao utilizar DateFormat.Parse

Tags: android, data, conversão-de-tipo

Pego a data e chamo o trocaFormatoDataTra

```
 private void makeJsonObjReq(){
    showProgressDialog();
    int id = ((AppController) this.getApplication()).getID();
    JsonObjectRequest jsonObjReq = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET,
            Const.URL_JSON_ARRAY_Editar_USU+"/"+id, null,
            new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                    Log.d(TAG, response.toString());
                //    hideProgressDialog();
                    JSONObject jsonobj = null;
                    int aJsonint = 0;
                    String aJsonString;
                    try {
                        jsonobj = new JSONObject(String.valueOf(response));
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    try {

                        //String dataresp = trocaFormatoDataTra(jsonobj.getString("nascimento"));
                        String dataresp = trocaFormatoDataTra(jsonobj.getString("nascimento"));
                        JsonNome = jsonobj.getString("nome");
                        JsonNascimento = dataresp;

                        //ADD VALORES CAMPOS
                        NomeTraEd.setText(JsonNome);
                        NascimentoTraEd.setText(JsonNascimento);


                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            VolleyLog.d(TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());
            hideProgressDialog();
        }
    });
    // Adding request to request queue
    AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(jsonObjReq,
            tag_json_obj);

}
```

Tenho o seguinte método

```
 public String trocaFormatoDataTra(String data) {
  //data recebe Dec 31, 1969 12:00:00 AM
    String formatoDeEntrada = "MMM dd, yyyy h:mm:ss";
    String formatoDeSaida = "dd/MM/yyyy";
    SimpleDateFormat dateFormatEntrada = new SimpleDateFormat(formatoDeEntrada);
    SimpleDateFormat dateFormatSaida = new SimpleDateFormat(formatoDeSaida);

    Date dataOriginal = null;
    String dataTrocada = null;

    try {
        //Transforma a String em Date
        dataOriginal = dateFormatEntrada.parse(data);
        //Transforma a Date num String com o formato pretendido
        dataTrocada = dateFormatSaida.format(dataOriginal);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        //Erro se não foi possível fazer o parse da Data
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return dataTrocada;
}
```

Logcat de erro

```
10-29 15:28:42.430      981-981/spac.com.br.jobbroker W/System.err﹕ 

java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "Dec 31, 1969 12:00:00 AM" (at offset 0)
10-29 15:28:42.460      981-981/spac.com.br.jobbroker W/System.err﹕ at java.text.DateFormat.parse(DateFormat.java:626)
10-29 15:28:42.460      981-981/spac.com.br.jobbroker W/System.err﹕ at spac.com.br.jobbroker.Editar.Editar_Perfil_trabalhador.trocaFormatoDataTra(Editar_Perfil_trabalhador.java:319)  //A Linha desse erro é essa dataOriginal = dateFormatEntrada.parse(data);
10-29 15:28:42.460      981-981/spac.com.br.jobbroker W/System.err﹕ at spac.com.br.jobbroker.Editar.Editar_Perfil_trabalhador$2.onResponse(Editar_Perfil_trabalhador.java:209)
10-29 15:28:42.460      981-981/spac.com.br.jobbroker W/System.err﹕ at spac.com.br.jobbroker.Editar.Editar_Perfil_trabalhador$2.onResponse(Editar_Perfil_trabalhador.java:191)
10-29 15:28:42.460      981-981/spac.com.br.jobbroker W/System.err﹕ at com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonRequest.deliverResponse(JsonRequest.java:65)
10-29 15:28:42.472      981-981/spac.com.br.jobbroker W/System.err﹕ at com.android.volley.ExecutorDelivery$ResponseDeliveryRunnable.run(ExecutorDelivery.java:99)
10-29 15:28:42.472      981-981/spac.com.br.jobbroker W/System.err﹕ at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
10-29 15:28:42.472      981-981/spac.com.br.jobbroker W/System.err﹕ at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
10-29 15:28:42.472      981-981/spac.com.br.jobbroker W/System.err﹕ at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
10-29 15:28:42.472      981-981/spac.com.br.jobbroker W/System.err﹕ at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
10-29 15:28:42.480      981-981/spac.com.br.jobbroker W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-29 15:28:42.480      981-981/spac.com.br.jobbroker W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
10-29 15:28:42.480      981-981/spac.com.br.jobbroker W/System.err﹕ at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
10-29 15:28:42.490      981-981/spac.com.br.jobbroker W/System.err﹕ at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
10-29 15:28:42.490      981-981/spac.com.br.jobbroker W/System.err﹕ at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Obrigado novamente deu certo!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Este tipo de erro é frequente quando são utilizadas funções de conversão cujo comportamento depende do ***Locale***(combinação lingua/país).

A classe *SimpleDateFormat*, quando construída com o construtor que aceita apenas uma *string*, usa como *Locale* aquele que está definido no dispositivo.

No caso presente, o dispositivo que está a executar o código, deve estar definido para utilizar o *Locale pt_BR* ou *pt_PT*.

O problema surge porque estamos a tentar converter uma data que tem os meses em inglês usando a classe configurada para usar português.

A classe *SimpleDateFormat* tem outro construtor que recebe também um *Locale*.
Ao passar o *Locale* indicamos quais a regras que a *SimpleDateFormat* deve utilizar.

Neste caso em vez de utilizar

```
new SimpleDateFormat(formatoDeEntrada)
```

devemos utilizar

```
new SimpleDateFormat(formatoDeEntrada, Locale.US)
```