# Trocar o formato de uma data(hora) que está numa String

Tags: java, android, string, data

Tenho duas strings que recebem horas, no caso, ArrivalTime e DepartureTime. O formato que vem é HH:MM:SS.
Gostaria de formatar esta string para HH:MM como posso fazer isso?

Insiro este texto em ToggleButtons (setTextOn e setTextOff).

Comment: Você tem a data num tipo *Date* ou está numa string?

Comment: Ela vem de um Json, convertida pra String.

Comment: Relacionado [Problema com conversão android](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/34655/problema-com-convers%c3%a3o-android)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Você precisa usar o **SimpleDateFormat**, dessa forma:

```
public String getHourFormat(String hour){

    SimpleDateFormat dateFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
    Date date;
    String displayValue = null;

    try {
        date = dateFormatter.parse(hour);
        SimpleDateFormat timeFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");
        displayValue = timeFormatter.format(date);

    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return displayValue;

}
```

Basta você chamar o método passando o valor, exemplo:

```
texview.setText(getHourFormat("18:00:00"));
```

O resultado no textview será `18:00`

Comment: As respostas atendem, mas esta era exatamente o que estava precisando. Muito obrigado!

Answer (score 5):

Método genérico que converte um qualquer formato em um qualquer outro:

```
public static String trocaFormatoData(String data, String formatoDeEntrada, String formatoDeSaida) {

    SimpleDateFormat dateFormatEntrada = new SimpleDateFormat(formatoDeEntrada);
    SimpleDateFormat dateFormatSaida = new SimpleDateFormat(formatoDeSaida);

    Date dataOriginal = null;
    String dataTrocada = null;

    try {
        //Transforma a String em Date
        dataOriginal = dateFormatEntrada.parse(data);
        //Transforma a Date num String com o formato pretendido
        dataTrocada = dateFormatSaida.format(dataOriginal);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
       //Erro se não foi possível fazer o parse da Data
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return dataTrocada;
}
```

No seu caso use assim:

```
setTextOn.setText(trocaFormatoData(jsonValue, "HH:mm:ss", "HH:mm"));
```

Answer (score 1):

Uma maneira seria você converter para toString e quebrar essa string usando split

```
String string = "11:12:13"; 
String[] partes = string.split(":"); 
partes[0]; // 11
partes[1]; // 12
partes[2]; // 13
```

Comment: Usar os formatadores de data/hora nativos do Java (ex mais comum: `SimpleDateFormat`) daria um resultado mais robusto.